# How to group row into an array [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql

TableA:

```
date_time                     amount    note
2016-03-01 01:00.00.000000    100       "hi"
2016-03-01 02:00.00.000000    5         "hello"
2016-03-01 03:00.00.000000    2         "foo"
2016-04-01 00:00.00.000000    60        "bar"
```

I need to output the final table like this:

```
ProcessedTable

grouped_date_time     row          total
2016-03-01            RowA         107
2016-04-01            RowB         60
```

RowA is an array of JSON objects from all rows in the first group:

```
[
  { date_time:2016-03-01 01:00.00.000000, amount:100, note:"hi"}, 
  { date_time:2016-03-01 02:00.00.000000, amount:5, note:"hello"}, 
  { date_time:2016-03-01 03:00.00.000000, amount:2, note:"foo"}
]
```

RowB is an array of JSON objects from all rows in the first group:

```
[
  { date_time:2016-04-01 00:00.00.000000, amount:60, note:"bar"} 
]
```

Currently I have query like this

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date_time), array_agg(amount)
    FROM table_a
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date_time)
```

I am not sure what to put for `array_agg(amount)` to extract out the whole JSON object as a column, and the total amount for each group.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date_time), 
    JSON_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(table_a)) AS row, 
    SUM(amount) AS total
FROM table_a GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', date_time);
```

While `ROW_TO_JSON(table_a)` converts a SQL row to a JSON object, `JSON_AGG` collects all objects into a JSON array.

Output (with use of `JSONB_PRETTY`):

```
     date_trunc      |                    row                     | total 
---------------------+--------------------------------------------+-------
 2016-03-01 00:00:00 | [                                         +|   107
                     |     {                                     +| 
                     |         "note": "hi",                     +| 
                     |         "amount": 100,                    +| 
                     |         "date_time": "2016-03-01T01:00:00"+| 
                     |     },                                    +| 
                     |     {                                     +| 
                     |         "note": "hello",                  +| 
                     |         "amount": 5,                      +| 
                     |         "date_time": "2016-03-01T02:00:00"+| 
                     |     },                                    +| 
                     |     {                                     +| 
                     |         "note": "foo",                    +| 
                     |         "amount": 2,                      +| 
                     |         "date_time": "2016-03-01T03:00:00"+| 
                     |     }                                     +| 
                     | ]                                          | 
 2016-04-01 00:00:00 | [                                         +|    60
                     |     {                                     +| 
                     |         "note": "bar",                    +| 
                     |         "amount": 60,                     +| 
                     |         "date_time": "2016-04-01T00:00:00"+| 
                     |     }                                     +| 
                     | ]                                          |
```

**Edit:** The query can be even further simplified by removing `ROW_TO_JSON`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date_time), JSON_AGG(t) AS row, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM table_a t GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', date_time);
```

Comment: whoa. you're passing `table_a` to a function. I had to do complicated gymnastics to get an individual row. This is neat!

Comment: @Krishna: No, I don't put the table to `ROW_TO_JSON`. `ta` is a reference for the current row. You can use a table alias or a comma separated list of column names as well.

Comment: the more you know! Kinda makes sense that there would be such functionality built in. My first attempt was to pass `*` to `row_to_json` which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can select whole row before passing into `row_to_json`, use `cte` and `group by`

```
with t1 as(
select date_time as dt, amount,
   (select row_to_json(this_row) 
      from (select t.date_time, t.amount, t.note) as this_row) as rowdict
from table_a as t
)
select date_trunc('day', dt), array_agg(rowdict) as row, sum(amount) as total
from t1
group by 1;
```